# How to fire an event when a table data is in focus & a key is pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some td elements with a class name, I need to fire a pop up window when one of these td is in focus & a key <kbd>F9</kbd> is pressed. I've tried following:

```
$(document.body).keypress(function (e) {

        $(".HolidayName").hover(function () {

            if (e.keyCode == 120) {
                //alert("first");
                SelectedItemOfListOfValue('HolidayNameWindowGrid');
                HolidayNameWindow.open(); //Open Popup
            }

        }, function () {

        });

        });
```

I'm using hover since focus can't be used with td elements (as per my search, not sure). But the current output is not what I desired. At the moment it fires the pop up after pressing the key once & hovering the mouse over that td.

Comment: Your code is merely creating a hover event function **when** you press a key. You need to keep a flag of whether you're hovering over the td and use that flag inside the keypress event code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Use event delegation to delegate keyup event on 'td.HolidayName' :

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'td.HolidayName', function(e) {     
  if (e.which == 120) {
   SelectedItemOfListOfValue('HolidayNameWindowGrid');
   HolidayNameWindow.open(); //Open Popup
 } 

});
```

Comment: Clever use of event delegation!

Comment: Is there something wrong with this demo? The keyup event isn't firing at all. http://jsbin.com/usETuwAP/4/edit

Comment: @ m59 just add a tabindex to your td.hover http://jsbin.com/usETuwAP/8/. @Jain never said anything about hover, he wanted keyup to fire when td has a "focus".

Comment: @Jain was using hover to emulate focus. Read the first part of his question. The second part only says, "I'm using hover since focus can't be used with td elements"

Answer (score 2):

Add an event listener to watch for the press on the <kbd>F9</kbd> key (keyCode 120). Also, set a flag variable when the `td` is hovered/un-hovered. When <kbd>f9</kbd> is pressed, check that the hover flag is set. If it is, respond however you want!

**[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/usETuwAP/1/edit)**

```
var hovered = 0;

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 120 && hovered) {
    console.log('td hovered and f9 pressed!');
  }
});

$('td.hover').hover(function() {
  hovered^= true; 
}, function() {
  hovered^= true; 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, I got exact answer from alex.

Comment: @Jain His answer will fire your function no matter what is hovered. Didn't you want to open the popup only if a certain element was hovered when the key is pressed?

Comment: not really, his code is working fine for me. I wanted to fire the pop up with f9 press event only when any of the TDs with class holidayname is in focus. its doing exactly that.

Comment: Now its not firing with the hover event actually, I need to first click or navigated to that td using tab then pressing f9 is firing the pop up, which is exactly I was looking for.

Comment: @m59, Im using event delegation. Notice the '.HolidayName' after 'keyup'.

Comment: @AlexShilman ahhhhh, smart! I get it now. Could you update your answer with that explanation? It wasn't immediately clear to me because of the specific classname. I prefer more generic answers because they're more adaptable to future readers. Anyway, good answer! Upvote for you!

Comment: Thanks to all once again... :)